# Write to multiple outputs by key Scalding Hadoop, one MapReduce Job

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, cascading, scalding

How can you write to multiple outputs dependent on the key using Scalding(/cascading) in a single Map Reduce Job.  I could of course use `.filter` for all the possible keys, but that is a horrible hack, which will fire up many jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [TemplatedTsv](https://twitter.github.io/scalding/api/index.html#com.twitter.scalding.TemplatedTsv) in Scalding (from version 0.9.0rc16 and up), exactly same as Cascading TemplateTsv.

```
Tsv(args("input"), ('COUNTRY, 'GDP))
.read
.write(TemplatedTsv(args("output"), "%s", 'COUNTRY))
// it will create a directory for each country under "output" path in Hadoop mode.
```

Comment: This looks even more flexible than what I requested!! Thanks.  Could you say from which Scalding version this is? Is it 0.10.0 and above? or 0.9.0?

Comment: From codebase, it looks to be available from 0.9.0rc16 version.

Comment: @morazow is there any way to drop the fields used in the template string?  In your example, basically I want the resulting files to have only the 'GDP' field in the resulting output.

Comment: @Syllepsis That is really good question; but, I do not know if it is possible with current TemplatedTsv implementation.
However, you can make another, your own, MyTemplatedTsv like here https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/0.11.0/scalding-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/scalding/TemplateSource.scala#L99-L105 and add "override val fields = Fields.ALL" and specify the fields to be written when calling that tap. Could you please reply here if you test that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [MultipleOutputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) and extrapolate from these other SO questions to write a custom output class using the output format: 
[Create Scalding Source like TextLine that combines multiple files into single mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917404/create-scalding-source-like-textline-that-combines-multiple-files-into-single-ma),
[Compress Output Scalding / Cascading TsvCompressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939577/compress-output-scalding-cascading-tsvcompressed)

Answer (score 0):

[This suggestion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cascading-user/5vp25Z9feCo/4zeFlDrMN0IJ) on the Cascading User group suggests to use [Cascading TemplateTap](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/javadoc/cascading/tap/hadoop/TemplateTap.html). Not sure how to connect this to Scalding though.

Comment: That certainly looks promising, care to provide Scalding code for people's copy and paste needs? :)