# Apache Spark groupByKey -> saveAsTextfile

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have a huge XML File containing many unsorted rows:

```
<row>
  <field name="f1">group</field>
  <field name="f2">number</field>
  <field name="f3">number2</field>
</row>
```

and i want to use spark for extracting each group (f1) with distinct numbers into a seperate file.

for now i tried to extract all groups (~ 50) first, using map, distinct and collect, then iterating over this group-array. using the original RDD, i filter all rows matching the current group, saveToTextFile.
 - works, but i am pretty sure that this way is the least efficient one.

therefore i changed my xml importer to return (f1, (f2,f3)) and tried to:

```
rdd.groupByKey(numPartitions).mapPartitions(part => {
  part.map(data => {
    val group = data._1
    val numbers = data._2
    ...
}
```

this is how far i get, because since numbers now is Iterable[(String,String)], and not an RDD.

my idea was basicaly (pseudo code):

```
 rdd.groupByKey(numPartitions).map((group, numbers) => { 
    numbers.distinct.map(OutputFormatter(_)).
      saveAsTextFile(s"$target$group") 
 }
```

numPartitions here should match the size of workers, to have one group per worker (i`d also like to benchmark behavior here, but this is OT)

is it correct that numbers *cannot* be a RDD here, since groupByKey needs to collect data first?
if not, what did i miss?

is there a common best-practice for this operation? i am new to spark/hadoop/etc

Thank you.

Comment: No you don't want the `numPartitions` to be the same as the number of workers, you want around 2 - 4 partitions per CPU, but in general I tend to use many many more for stability and performance.  Anyway I think as I understand it the question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995040/write-to-multiple-outputs-by-key-spark-one-spark-job

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following approach, I guess it's similar in spirit to your original solution with the filtering, except we de not explicitly collect to an array. Is this close to what you need?

```
def extractGroup(row: Row) = ???

def extractNumbers(row: Row) = ???

val keyed = rdd.keyBy(extractGroup _) 

keyed
  .map { case (group, row) => group }
  .distinct
  .foreach { group =>
     keyed
       .filter { _._1 == group } 
       .map { case (_, row) => extractNumbers(row) }
       .distinct
       .map(OutputFormatter(_))
       .saveAsTextFile(???)
   }
```