# Can I split a Spark RDD into two tables, and then perform a join on them?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large TSV data file that contains, lumped together, the fact table and its dimension tables. I'm wondering if its possible through Spark, to divide/partition that single file into different 'tables', and then perform a join to normalize them?

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Apply filter on the baseRDD to get both factRDD & dimensionsRDD, then you can do a join on them.

```
val baseRDD = sc.textFile("...")  
val factRDD = baseRDD.filter(func1)  
val dimensionsRDD = baseRD.filter(func2)  
factRDD.join(dimentionsRDD)
```

Comment: thank you, but would it be possible to do it without parsing the RDD twice? I know I'm nit picking, just curious.

Comment: @AlbertLim - That's a valid concern. This is similar to the problem [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23995040/877069). Having to scan over the same data more than once is definitely suboptimal.