# PairRDD(K, L<V>) to multiple files by key serializing each value in L<V>

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a PairRDD with a set of key and list of values, each value in the list is a json which I already loaded beginning of my spark app, how can I iterate over each value of the list in my pair RDD to transform it to a string then save the whole content of the key to a file?

my input files look like:

```
{cat:'red',value:'asd'}
{cat:'green',value:'zxc'}
{cat:'red',value:'jkl'}
```

The PairRDD looks like

```
('red', [{cat:'red',value:'asd'},{cat:'red',value:'jkl'}])
('green', [{cat:'green',value:'zxc'}])
```

so as you can see I I'd like to serialize each json in the value list back to string so I can easily saveAsTextFile(), ofcourse I'm trying to save a separate file for each key

The way I got here:

```
rawcatRdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://x.x.x.../unstructured/cat-0-500.txt")
import json
categoriesJson = rawcatRdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
categories = categoriesJson

catByDate = categories.map(lambda x: (x['cat'], x)
catGroup = catByDate.groupByKey()
catGroupArr = catGroup.mapValues(lambda x : list(x))
```

Ideally I want to create a **cat-red.txt** that looks like:

```
{cat:'red',value:'asd'}
{cat:'red',value:'jkl'}
```

and the same for the rest of the keys.

[I already looked at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995040/write-to-multiple-outputs-by-key-spark-one-spark-job) but I'm slightly lost as host to process each value in the list before I save the contents to a file

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Spark 1.5