# spark save dataframe to multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This question has a partial answer here : [Write to multiple outputs by key Spark - one Spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995040/write-to-multiple-outputs-by-key-spark-one-spark-job/37150604#37150604)

But i want to save a Dataframe to multiple csv files.

```
df =  sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(name=u'name1', website=u'http://1', url=u'1'),
 Row(name=u'name2', website=u'http://1', url=u'1'),
 Row(name=u'name3', website=u'https://fsadf', url=u'2'),
 Row(name=u'name4', website=None, url=u'3')])

df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').partitionBy("name").save("dataset.csv")
```

And i'm using spark-csv (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to handle csv data.

One more thing, `df.write.partitionBy("column").json("dataset")` , saves data to multiple directories like `column=value1, column=value2` etc , but the column itself is not present in the data.

what if i need that column in the output dataset ??

Comment: _what if i need that column in the output dataset ??_ - then you'll have to either create partitions manually (without `partitionBy`) or do a second sweep.

Comment: @zero323, i'm ready to create partitions manually or do a second sweep , but i'm not sure how to do that . could you please help me ?

Comment: Option a) After save, load data directory by directory and overwrite with added column b) collect a range of unique values and perform separate filter and write for each. If makes to `repartition` data by the column of interest first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There is also another possible trick - just duplicate partitioning column. `dt.withColumn("key", col("name")).write.partitionBy("key")`

Comment: thanks, last one did the trick.