# NoSuchMethodException : RDDMultipleTextOutpu‌​tFormat.<init>(), while using MultipleTextOutputFormat in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to make use of MultipleTextOutputFormat to write the data in customized way, here is the example that I am referring to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26051042/2485454

However, I am getting an error after executing above code :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException :
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$RDDMultipleTextOutpu‌​tFormat.()

Comment: You have an invisible space between `u` and `t` in `RDDMultipleTextOutpu‌​tFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible diagnose this fully without a project, but when you run into `NoSuchMethodException`s, you can be pretty sure the issue is a compile-time vs. run-time dependency conflict. Perhaps you are using a library that's pulling in a mismatched spark or hadoop library. Or perhaps you're just compiling against a different spark version than you are running on.

Try removing all your extra libraries and/or running the code in a pure spark REPL and build it back up from there.