# How to split a large text into smaller files based on an id column using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a collection of TSV files on Azure blob storage that I need to split based on the ID of the record.

e.g. a record format is:

```
|ID|Name|Address   |
|--|----|----------|
|34|Stephen|A House|
```

I want to split on ID and store all records by ID e.g. 34.csv

To clarify also, the data has millions of rows with up to 80k different possible IDs - the solution outlined in [Write to multiple outputs by key Spark - one Spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995040/write-to-multiple-outputs-by-key-spark-one-spark-job) is too slow. It takes well over an hour to process roughly 80 million rows which is far too slow!